# How should the search filter work in general. what does the user expects?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, search

I have 2 websites to compare. box8.in and zomato.com.

**what i think**

In http://box8.in the user expects to get the restaurants present in that location as soon as he/she types in the location in the search box.
[image: Box8.in]

Problem

- But the user flow breaks and the user is asked to input detailed location.

Question

- Does it provides good UX to the user or search should perform like the second website http://zomato.com.
  [image: Zomato.com]

Comment: Are these food delivery sites? I'm a little unclear as to what they do...

Answer (score 1):

In case of Box8 when user selects location as Bangalore, then while asking for detailed location provide auto suggestion option as user starts typing in. It needs to refine it's area as per city selected.

In case of zomato it has got simpler way of searching restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

I guess box.in and zomato perform slightly different functions even though both deal with cuisines and the like.

IMHO the search of box.in is broken for it becomes a hassle when user has mistyped the location ( i selected Bangalore and then selected Noida for suburb  ) .

Whereas the UX of Zomato is much  more simpler  and searching restaurants is easier .

If you are looking for an UX where user can search for a particular restaurant or restaurants in an area. i'd recommend you take a look at **Pizza Hut's store locator**, also [swiggy](https://www.swiggy.com) and [foodpanda](https://www.foodpanda.in/) both  follow the same UX.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Both Zomato and Box8 are doing things differently because they are different. The question you are asking is a generalization. I do not think such generalization can be made across industries. Just because both are fruits, you can not compare apples and oranges.

If you are looking for a case to case basis feedback then it is a different discussion. Here Zomato, (or Foodpanda, Swiggy) is doing a much better job than Box8. They are locking down the city location and then allowing the user to search for either the food type or the restaurant. This placeholder text helps the user to decide if he wants to use that feature or not.

Conceptually, even Box8 UI is not bad. However, it has failed in implementation. It creates a lot of confusion, increases lot many clicks and in turn results in frustration.

I remember the early days of Zomato when they were in few cities. Those cities were upfront on their site, with the technology available at that time. A user could quickly surmise if the site is helpful to her or not.

Box8 allows me all sort of permutations and combinations. It allows me to enter a city and then informs that Box8 is not available there. It also allows me to jump cities and does not zoom in after entering the first one. There is tremendous confusion about how much granular you are supposed to go. Overall, it is a case of bad implementation.

Coming back to your question, the search is functioning properly, but still the UX is terrible. If they are offering such a widely free entry of location, they should be available at those places.

Long story short, users expect their search to lead them to a meaningful result, which does not happen always in the case of Box8 resulting in a bad user experience.